# How to open multiple url/link in separate windows at once using JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to open multiple pages of my JSF application using a command link in primefaces. Is there a way to do this using a backing bean? I need to open them at the same time because I need to display the pages to different monitors. Each pages has a `<p:poll />` tag with the same interval and my goal is to make the UI look like updating at the same time.

```
<p:link outcome="/admin/page1">
      <span class="ui-button-text">page1</span>
</p:link>
<p:link outcome="/admin/page2">
      <span class="ui-button-text">page2</span>
</p:link>
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{someBean.openLinks}" />
```

Comment: @Kukeltje Can <p:link /> open multiple links at once?

Comment: No, not as is. But you could add an `onclick` handler which clicks the other link. JavaScript it as you would using plain HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this on the client side using JavaScript to "click" the links when the button's action is completed. Advantages are you can use the button to process what's needed and also your links will be processed as they normally would if a user clicked on them. To open links in a new window add `target` to them (it accepts all values a normal plain html `a href` accepts). So, I would suggest:

```
<p:link id="myLink1" outcome="/admin/page1" target="target1">
      <span class="ui-button-text">page1</span>
</p:link>
<p:link id="myLink2" outcome="/admin/page2" target="target2">
      <span class="ui-button-text">page2</span>
</p:link>
<p:commandButton action="#{someBean.yourAction}"
                 oncomplete="openLinks()" />
```

You should add a JavaScript function `openLinks`:

```
function openLinks(){
    document.getElementById("myForm:myLink1").click();
    document.getElementById("myForm:myLink2").click();
}
```

I don't know what naming containers you are using, just use your browser's debug tools to inspect the link and find the actual `id`. If you have anything like `j_idtXxx` in it, make sure to set an `id` to the corresponding naming container.

Keep in mind that JSF always generates HTML (with JavaScript and CSS) for the client-side. So many you can apply the same plain html solutions to them (the `openLinks` JavaScript function would be identical for a plain html solution without any JSF).

Answer (score 1):

this command line allows you to open a link from a managed bean :

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('" + url + "')");
```